# How to display instructions for custom payment method

Tags: magento2, module, payment-gateway

I have finally gave up. I spent 2 whole days trying to do this but I finally could not.

I am developing a custom payment method which needs to show instructions for the customer before the actual purchase.

That simple thing could not be made.

First, this is the layout definition (checkout_index_index.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="renders" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <!-- merge payment method renders here -->
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="desytec_transbank_methods" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Desytec_Transbank/js/view/payment/method-renderer</item>
                                                                    <item name="methods" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="webpay" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="isBillingAddressRequired" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

The renderer is:

```
define(
    [
        'uiComponent',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/renderer-list'
    ],
    function (
        Component,
        rendererList
    ) {
        'use strict';
        rendererList.push(
            {
                type: 'webpay',
                component: 'Desytec_Transbank/js/view/payment/method-renderer/webpay'
            }
        );

        return Component.extend({});
    }
);
```

And the webpay renderer is:

```
/*browser:true*/
/*global define*/
define(
    [
        'ko',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default',
    ],
    function (ko, Component) {
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Desytec_Transbank/payment/webpay'
            },
            /**
             * Get value of instruction field.
             * @returns {String}
             */
            getInstructions: function () {
                return window.checkoutConfig.payment.instructions[this.item.method];
            }            
        });
    }
);
```

The template is:

```
<div class="payment-method" data-bind="css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked())}">
    <div class="payment-method-title field choice">
        <input type="radio"
               name="payment[method]"
               class="radio"
               data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode()}, value: getCode(), checked: isChecked, click: selectPaymentMethod, visible: isRadioButtonVisible()"/>
        <label data-bind="attr: {'for': getCode()}" class="label"><span data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="payment-method-content">
        <div class="payment-method-billing-address">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion(getBillingAddressFormName()) -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
        <p data-bind="html: getInstructions()"></p>
        <div class="checkout-agreements-block">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('before-place-order') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button class="action primary checkout"
                        type="submit"
                        data-bind="
                        click: placeOrder,
                        attr: {title: $t('Place Order')},
                        css: {disabled: !isPlaceOrderActionAllowed()},
                        enable: (getCode() == isChecked())
                        "
                        disabled>
                    <span data-bind="text: $t('Place Order')"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And finally, this is the block:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Desytec\Transbank\Block\Form;
/**
 * Abstract class for Cash On Delivery and Bank Transfer payment method form
 */
abstract class Transbank extends \Magento\Payment\Block\Form
{
    /**
     * Instructions text
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_instructions;
    protected $_template = 'form/webpay.phtml';
    /**
     * Get instructions text from config
     *
     * @return null|string
     */
    public function getInstructions()
    {
        if ($this->_instructions === null) {
            /** @var \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod $method */
            $method = $this->getMethod();
            $this->_instructions = $method->getConfigData('instructions');
        }
        return $this->_instructions;
    }
}
```

What is missing here?

Regards
Jaime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was solved by following these instructions:

https://mage2.pro/t/630

and

https://mage2.pro/tags/checkout-config-provider

Comment: Hello jstuardo,
Can you explain how you added the instructions ?