# Magento 2: add html in custom Payment method

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, payment-methods

I created a new payment method in Magento 2 using the instructions [here](https://webkul.com/blog/create-custom-payment-method-magento2/)

The payment method is created successfully. However, I want to add instructions under the payment method in the red box in attached image.

[image]

I checked this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105120/how-to-display-instructions-for-custom-payment-method), but It didn't help.

I am using magento 2.1.5 EE

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add custom html in payment html file at

> app/code/Test/Testpayment/view/frontend/web/template/payment/mypayment.html

You can add your custom html before `<div class="actions-toolbar">`

```
<div class="payment-method" data-bind="css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked())}">
    <div class="payment-method-title field choice">
        <input type="radio"
               name="payment[method]"
               class="radio"
               data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode()}, value: getCode(), checked: isChecked, click: selectPaymentMethod, visible: isRadioButtonVisible()"/>
        <label data-bind="attr: {'for': getCode()}" class="label"><span data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div>ADD YOUR HTML HERE</div>
    <div class="payment-method-content">
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button class="action primary checkout"
                        type="submit"
                        data-bind="
                        click: placeOrder,
                        attr: {title: $t('Place Order')},
                        css: {disabled: !isPlaceOrderActionAllowed()},
                        enable: (getCode() == isChecked())
                        "
                        disabled>
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Place Order'"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now remove static payment template file from `pub/static/frontend/vendor/theme/en_US/Vendor_Module/template/payment`

Flush cache and try....!

OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: .....Its not working  ..... after clear cache .....@Prince

Comment: I am overwriting the payment template but need access to customer data, any idea which Helper class is used to get section data for the payment template html page since I don't see any information in layout XML files?